# How can I fill the table? (Python, Django)

Tags: python, django

I faced with a problem: I have 4 lists with data. And I need to fill the table with this data. It is the example of table:
[image: table]

So, as you already understood, at first column must be data from a first list, at second - second list, ...
I tried to make it:

```
{% for i in first_list %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{i}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

But It fill only first column and don`t know what I must do next... 
Help me, please!

Comment: Is it like all the lists are of the same length

Comment: Yes, all the list are the same length

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two things that you need to change.

- In the `views.py` file, rather than returning 4 different lists, return a  single zipped version of the lists like

  ```
  zipped_list = zip(first_list, second_list, third_list, fourth_list)
  ```

  Now this must be passed to the view file that is being rendered.

  ```
  context_dict = {'zipped_list': zipped_list, ......}
  ```

  and rendered as

  ```
  return render(request, 'your_view_file', context_dict)
  ```
- Now in the view file, you can modify the `for` template as

  ```
  {% for i in zipped_list %}
      <tr>
          <td>{{i.0}}</td>
          <td>{{i.1}}</td>
          <td>{{i.2}}</td>
          <td>{{i.3}}</td>        
      </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  ```

  **Note** You can even iterate the `<td>`'s so that it enables you to handle any number of columns and not just 4 columns.

  Example :

  ```
  {% for row in zipped_list %}
      <tr>
         {% for column in row %}
            <td>{{column}}</td>         
      </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  ```

Comment: You could do the `<td>`s in an inner loop through `i`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Wow!! That makes it more tidy. Updated in answer. Thanks for the tip!! :)